# should I use single or plural form here？

Tags: grammatical-number

> ...help the children draw the animal(s) they choose.

When each child can only choose one animal, which form is correct?

I guess plural form is correct here, since the "children" is in plural form.

Comment: You could "help the children draw the animal each chooses"--I think that works and covers the ground.

Comment: The child**ren** are plural, so you use animal**s** because the children as a whole will draw more than one animal. ('Help the children draw the animal they choose' would imply they all worked together on the same animal)

Comment: Concur with @marcellothearcane. As _the children as a whole will draw more than one animal_ you (presumably) will be helping with (the drawing of) multiple animals.

Comment: Possibly related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372667/individual-items-owned-by-one-another/372706#372706

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about only one animal to draw for all the children, then it can be kept singular. Here you are asking them to choose from, so are various animals to draw from, then plural.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [edit] to add [citations to reliable sources](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).